# Brownian motion and second derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\{B_t\}$ be Brownian motion with $B_0=x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $f\in C_c^2(\mathbb{R})$. According to page 11 of [this document](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/huiwang/classes/Am264/Archive/Brownian.pdf), we have that

$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)]-f(x)}{t}=\frac{1}{2}f''(x).$$
If you follow the reasoning, there is a point where the author obtains through 2 change of variables that
$$ \frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)]-f(x)}{t}=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\frac{f(x+\sqrt{t}\cdot y)-f(x)}{t}e^{-y^2}dy.$$
He then uses Taylor's formula to get that
$$f(x+\sqrt{t}y)-f(x)=f'(x)\sqrt{t}\cdot y+\frac{1}{2}f''\big(x+\xi\sqrt{t}\cdot y\big)ty^2.$$
for some $\xi\in[0,1]$ and concludes by dominated convergence that
$$\lim_{t\to 0 }\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\frac{f(x+\sqrt{t}\cdot y)-f(x)}{t}e^{-y^2}dy =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}\lim_{t\to 0}f''\big(x+\xi\sqrt t y\big)y^2e^{-y^2}dy.$$
I don't get the last step. First of all, why was he able to use dominated convergence in the end and not from the start since the integrand is the same? Second, how did he get rid of the term $f'(x)\sqrt{t} y$ in the Taylor expression?

Either something is weird about this whole argument or I'm missing a main point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this slowly.  We start with
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)]-f(x)}{t}=\mathbb{E}^x\left[\frac{f(B_t)-f(x)}{t}\right]
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x+\sqrt{t}\cdot y)-f(x)}{t}\frac{e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$
and we expand $f(x+\sqrt{t}\cdot y)$ to get
$$
\dots=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f'(x)\sqrt{t}\cdot y}{t}\frac{e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\frac12f''(x+\xi\sqrt{t}\cdot y)ty^2}{t}\frac{e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$
The first integrand is an odd function of $y$ so its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is 0 and we are left with the second integral
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)]-f(x)}{t}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac12f''(x+\xi\sqrt{t}\cdot y)\frac{y^2e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$

Now comes the DCT part.  Since $f\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\sup\lvert f''\rvert=M<\infty$ and so the integrand on the RHS is dominated by the integrable function $\frac12 M e^{-y^2}$.  Hence we have
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac12f''(x+\xi\sqrt{t}\cdot y)\frac{y^2e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac12f''(x+\xi\sqrt{t}\cdot y)\frac{y^2e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$
i.e.,
$$
\lim_{t\o 0}\frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)]-f(x)}{t}
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac12f''(x+\xi\sqrt{t}\cdot y)y^2\frac{e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac12f''(x).
$$

Comment: Okay the function being odd is didn't notice, thanks! The other question remains unanswered: why could he not use DCT from the start, since $f\in C_c^2$?

Comment: And one more question: why couldn't we have used DCT at this stage: 
$$\frac{\mathbb{E}^x[f(B_t)]-f(x)}{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{t\sqrt{t}}e^{-y^2/2t}\,dy ?$$

Comment: @UserA Without this calculation, what do you propose the dominating function be?

Comment: At this stage $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{t\sqrt{t}}e^{-y^2/2t}\,dy,$$
or even at this stage
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x+\sqrt{t}\cdot y)-f(x)}{t}e^{-y^2}\,dy $$
why can we not use DCT? Can't we use the fact that $f\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @UserA Again, which dominating function are you proposing?  Without a dominating function you can't apply DCT.

Comment: For $t$ small enough, can't we bound $$t^{-3/2}e^{-y^2/2t}$$ by some constant that is independent of $y$ and $t$? Therefore we get 
$$t^{-3/2}e^{-y^2/2t}|f(x+y)-f(x)|\leq M|f(x+y)-f(x)|\in L^1? $$

Comment: never mind this is not possible, I guess we really cannot used DCT before the computation